# Allocation: new(Foo) vs Foo{}

Tags: go

What is the difference between the following syntaxes for creating an object? Why 2 different methods if result is the same?

```
type Foo struct {
    X int
}

f1 := &Foo{}
f2 := new(Foo)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `new` is the only way to directly return a pointer of a native type (`int`, `float64`, `uint32`, ...) without creating a normal variable first then returning a pointer to it.

There's a longer discussion about it on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/K3Ys8qpml2Y and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/GDXFDJgKKSs, but basically it's useless.

Quote by Dave Cheney:

> new isn't going away, it can't, it's part of the guaranteed
>   specification for Go 1.
>
> You don't need to use it, most people don't, but that doesn't mean it
>   doesn't have a use.

Comment: Great answer, however IMHO some things just look nicer with `new`, eg `new(sync.WaitGroup)` which expresses the purpose much better than `&sync.WaitGroup{}`. This works very well for `struct`s with no public members.

Comment: Yeah but it's not "needed", just looks nicer but yeah I agree with you.